# Can I pushback messages in my class which extends Spring Integrations ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer?

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

I am extending the ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer to return the length from a tcp message header.  The problem is the very first message on the socket contains an 8 byte session without a header.  After that first message, all messages will have a header with a length (as well as some other fields).  The first 4 bytes of the header will always be a constant value.

I'd like to read the first 4 bytes to determine if I have a message with a header or a raw sessionId.

If not a header then I would push back the 4 bytes and return a length of 8.

If it was a header (first 4 bytes matched the constant value) then I would read the rest of the header, find the length field in the header and return that value.

Also, this application is probably using nio.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly; I did something similar a few years ago by writing a custom deserializer that used a `PushBackInputStream`.

You should be able to write a custom deserializer; wrap the IS in an `PushBackIS`. Peek at the start and push back if needed, then delegate to the `BALHS` to decode those messages with proper headers.